# are there any keyboard shortcuts for glimpse?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, glimpse

Are there any keyboard shortcuts for glimpse?
I've checked their website http://getglimpse.com/Help and http://getglimpse.com/Help/Configuration as well as the twitter hashtag #glimpse, but I'm getting no love.

I'm looking for something similar to how firebug lite uses F12 to show their console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are not currently any keyboard shortcuts for Glimpse.

It is a great idea though - suggest it on the [Glimpse User Voice](http://getglimpse.uservoice.com) page, or feel free to contribute.

Comment: straight from the proverbial horses' mouth no-less.

Answer (score 1):

There aren't any currently but I have implemented some of them myself using `javascript` so our developers could use keyboard shortcuts to turn on/ or star session. Something like

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $(document).keyup(function (event) {
                    var key = event.keyCode || event.charCode || 0;
                    if (key == 71 && event.altKey) {
                        document.cookie = 'glimpseState=On; path=/; expires=Sat, 01 Jan 2050 12:00:00 GMT;';
                        window.location.reload();
                    }
                    else if(key == 83 && event.altKey && event.ctrlKey) {
                        document.cookie = 'glimpseClientName=' + prompt('Client Name?') + '; path=/; expires=Sat, 01 Jan 2050 12:00:00 GMT;'; 
                        window.location.reload();
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
```